# PayPal IPN updates my database from third party sale sites but not from my own site

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

Been trying to figure this out as it has been bugging me now for a few days.

**What i am trying to do:**

Receive payment through my website using simpleCartJs and having a return ipn to update database with payment details.

**What works:**

- Payment through website works no problems at all.
- PayPal acknowledges the payment and send IPN message and receives code 200
- Payment through 3rd party sites DOES update my website

**What does not work**

- Payment through my website will not update the database however if payments are made through 3rd party sites (example ebay) do update my database as i have in PayPal IPN enabled with my ipn address

**What i currently have**

- I have enabled IPN notifications in Paypal and they are redirecting the file correctly (as third party do update database correctly)

**My IPN file**

```
require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/paypal.class.php');  

$p = new paypal_class;             

if ($p->validate_ipn() && !empty($p->ipn_data['payment_status']) && $p->ipn_data['payment_status'] == 'Completed') {



                    $mc_gross = $_POST['mc_gross'];
                    $payer_id = $_POST['payer_id'];
                    $payment_date = $_POST['payment_date'];
                    $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
                    $last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
                    $payer_email = $_POST['payer_email'];
                    $payment_status = $_POST['payment_status'];
                    $payer_status = $_POST['payer_status'];
                    $address_name = $_POST['address_name'];
                    $address_country = $_POST['address_country'];
                    $address_zip = $_POST['address_zip'];
                    $address_state = $_POST['address_state'];
                    $address_city = $_POST['address_city'];
                    $address_street = $_POST['address_street'];
                    $mc_shipping = $_POST['mc_shipping'];
                    $mc_currency = $_POST['mc_currency'];
                    $ipn_track_id = $_POST['ipn_track_id'];



    $stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT into orders (mc_gross, payer_id, payment_date, first_name, last_name, payer_email, payment_status, payer_status, address_name, address_country, address_zip, address_state, address_city, address_street, mc_shipping, mc_currency, ipn_track_id) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");    
    $stmt->bind_param("sssssssssssssssss", $mc_gross, $payer_id, $payment_date, $first_name, $last_name, $payer_email, $payment_status, $payer_status, $address_name, $address_country, $address_zip, $address_state, $address_city, $address_street, $mc_shipping, $mc_currency, $ipn_track_id);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();


    }
```

Any help in resolving this issue would be amazing please.

Comment: Which of those checks fails?

Comment: I have been debugging and just found out that its this part $p->ipn_data['payment_status'] == 'Completed'. if i remove it all works. Why does it not send back Completed

Comment: Please ignore the above comment as its not correct. I was doing testing and sending payment status as completed and not Complete.

Comment: Still have this issue if anyone can help